# I don't understand why my simple jquery scrollTop is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my hands on jquery scrollTop. But its returning me a bunch of errors in the console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null"

The weird thing is that I get a value that seems legit if I console.log() my x variable.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var x = $( window ).scrollTop();
    $( '.main-overlay > .e-1 > .element' ).css({'height': x + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $(window) instead $(document)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var x = $(window).scrollTop()
}
```